# I can't allow file execute as a program

Tags: java, minecraft, chromebook

I downloaded a  `.jar` game and it says it isn't good for my Chromebook.

When I say allow to download and it's finished, I'm going to my downloads folder and when I want to "allow execute file as a program" the box isn't there, it's blocked. I run Linux from a Chromebook with crouton Xfce.

BTW the game is Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

In the file explorer go to the edit tab in the top bar and click preferances (its the one at the bottom) and you will be presented with a window like this[image: File Explorer preferances]

go to the behaviors tab then under executeable files ensure that the option is set to always ask
[image]

then try again

Answer (score 1):

In order to run Minecraft open the terminal and type:

```
java -jar ~/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
```

This assumes that the Minecraft.jar file is in your `home/Minecraft` directory.

To automate the start with a shortcut please create a `Minecraft.sh` file in your home directory with this content:

```
java -jar ~/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
```

Then create a desktop file `Minecraft.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Play Minecraft
Exec=/home/your_user_name/Minecraft.sh
Path=/home/your_user_name/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/32/access.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Games;
```

Please change your_user_name to your user name.
You also need to set executable the Minecraft.sh file by typing in terminal:

```
chmod +x Minecraft.sh
```

You can change the icon file afterwards if you are not happy with the above icon.

Then you can execute Minecraft by a desktop shortcut.

Comment: Be sure you have installed java in your system.

Comment: Just mention in your post that they can instalk openjdk via apt get. It works perfectly fine with Minecraft and is less troublesome than Oracle java to install